# ElK stack AWS S3 log grok pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3, elastic-stack

Can someone help me creating a grook pattern for this kind of log:

```
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 3E57427F3EXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 7 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 891CE47D2EXAMPLE REST.GET.LOGGING_STATUS - "GET /mybucket?logging HTTP/1.1" 200 - 242 - 11 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be A1206F460EXAMPLE REST.GET.BUCKETPOLICY - "GET /mybucket?policy HTTP/1.1" 404 NoSuchBucketPolicy 297 - 38 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:01:00 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 7B4A0FABBEXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 33 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:01:57 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be DD6CC733AEXAMPLE REST.PUT.OBJECT s3-dg.pdf "PUT /mybucket/s3-dg.pdf HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 4406583 41754 28 "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:03:21 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be BC3C074D0EXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 28 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -
```

I have to analize them but I don't really know the way to create a grook filter for those logs, and also get @timestamp from them, thanks a lot!

Comment: http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

This grok debugger tool is also useful: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the grok pattern show below.

```
%{WORD:Bucket_Owner} %{WORD:bucket_name} %{DATA:timestamp} %{IP:Remote_IP} %{WORD:Requester} %{WORD:Request} %{DATA:Rest} %{WORD:HTTP_Status} \- %{NUMBER:Bytes_Sent} \- %{NUMBER:Object_Size} \- \"-" \"%{DATA:S3_console}" \-
```